# DB connection to the AWS istance

Tags: boto3, robotframework, dbconnection, aws-session-manager

I need to set up PostgreSQL db connection for AWS instance.
First i need to create a tunnel to the instance.
I can do this with AWS CLI and session manager, by running:

`aws ssm start-session --target <instanceID> --document-name AWS-   StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost --parameters '{"host":["host"], "portNumber":["5432"], "localPortNumber":["5432"]}'`

But when I trying to do this in Robot test using boto3 library:

```
@keyword(name="AWS Start Tunnel")
    def start_tunnel(self, instanceID: str) -> str:
        ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
        response = ssm_client.start_session(
            Target=instanceID,
            DocumentName='AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost',
            Reason='Robot Test',
            Parameters={'host': ['host'], 
                'portNumber': ['5432'],
                'localPortNumber': ['5432']} 
            )      
        return response
```

It is creates the session but looks like not connected to it, because I cannot connect to the db.
Maybe I need to have a webSocket connection also?

AWS CLI is works.
test with boto3 - not.

Comment: How are you connecting to the db, what's the connection string? Also, while the tunnel is running - can you connect successfully with any other client, a desktop or CLI one, not RF?